# Is it possible to access a variable from another class?

Tags: java, class, variables

Is it possible to access variable *abc* directly from a subclass?

I know its possible by changing *abc* to Static, but I don't want to do this.

main:

```
public class main {

    public subclass subclass1 = new subclass();
    public boolean abc = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        main menu1 = new main();
    }

    public main(){
        while(true){
            if(abc = true){
                System.out.println("true");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

subclass:

```
public class subclass {

    public subclass(){
        .abc = true; //possible to access abc of main?
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `if(abc = true){` should be `if(abc){`. The correct operator to use is `==` but in this case it is redundant.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Or abc == true

Comment: I don't know how, that is why I asking -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `subclass` class isn't subclassing `main`, so it can't directly access `abc`.  It's confusing to call it `subclass`, because it subclasses only `Object` (implicitly).

It needs to have a reference to an instance of the `main` class, then it can access `abc` through that instance.  That will work because `abc` is `public`.

**UPDATE**

Example:

```
public class Main
{
    public subclass subclass1;
    public boolean abc = false;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main menu1 = new Main();
        menu1.subclass1 = new Subclass(menu1);
        System.out.println(menu1.abc);
    }
}

public class Subclass
{
    private Main myMain;
    public Subclass(Main main)
    {
        myMain = main;
        myMain.abc = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 1):

There are a multitude of things wrong with your code.

1. Subclass is not a subclass of anything, in order for it to be a
   subclass it must extend another class by use of the keyword extends, `Bus extends Vehicle` (by default all classes in
   java only extend Object).
2. You have declared `abc` as public, this
   means it is accessible to everyone who has an instance of the class
   main by use of the dot operator on the instance. You can achieve this by creating an instance of `main` in your `subclass`

   ```
   main m = new main();
   public subclass() {

      m.abc = true;
   }
   ```
3. You will also have to remove `public subclass subclass1 = new subclass();` from main. The way you have made these classes subclass needs main needs subclass needs main needs subclass....circular references.
4. You will never be able to access an instance of the class because of the `while(true)` inside the constructor of `main`. This will run forever and never allow the constructor to finish. You will have to remove the `while(true)` statement, you can check whether `abc` has indeed been changed by doing the following

   ```
   main m = new main();
   public subclass() {
      System.out.println("Value of abc? "+m.abc);
      m.abc = true;
      System.out.println("Value of abc? "+m.abc);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is Simple inheritance and because abc access modifier is public, you should be able to use in child class without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to access `abc`, then you would have to have an instance of your `main` class:

```
Main m = new Main();
m.abc = "something";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't make abc static it will only exist in an instance (or object) of "main".
So to access it you will need to have a reference to the object.
So one thing you could do is ask for Main in SubClass's constructor (you should follow the [java conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)) like:

```
public class SubClass {
    private final Main main;
    public SubClass(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
        main.abc = true;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public SubClass subClass1 = new SubClass(this);
}
```

or if SubClass is really only for Main's use you could make it an inner class.

```
public class Main {
    public class SubClass {
        public SubClass() {
            //You can access Main's variables here and in case of ambiguity by doing
            Main.this.abc = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can create a Main in SubClass.

```
public class SubClass {
    public SubClass() {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.abc = true;
    }
}
```

(SubClass naming is a bit weird here and I think you might want to learn a bit more about objects/instances, or OOP in general.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple inheritance if both classes are related. Otherwise,

```
  m.abc= true
```

Would be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

You can access abc in sub class if it extends class main. Please find below a sample

```
public class Test {
Boolean abc = false;
Test()
{
    if(abc)
    {
        System.out.println("Test():True");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Test():False");
    }
}
void method()
{
    if(abc)
    {
        System.out.println("Method():True");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Method():False");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Test1 child= new Test1();
    child.method();//Parent method (abc change will reflect)
    Test parent = new Test();//Directly calling parent constructor so abc is false

}
```

}

child class

```
public class Test1 extends Test 
{
    Test1()
    {
        this.abc=true;
    }

}
```

ouput will be

```
Test():False
Method():True
Test():False
```

Comment: Srry, I can't use extend because I extend from another class

Comment: With out creating the object of the main class you can't access the variable abc inside sub class. Once if you creating the main class object in sub class you can call abc like main m = new main();. m.abc. Sorry If I am not matching with your requirement